# stdarg.h, new.h, float.h files missing in iOS 4.3 SDK (XCode 4)

Tags: xcode, ios

It seems files like stdarg.h, new.h, float.h are missing in iOS 4.3 SDK. These files however were available in the earlier versions of the SDK (and XCode).

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think they are missing?

Comment: I am not able to find them at  the expected location, i.e. /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/include